# Selecting data where it does not equal a number of specified IDs

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to run a MySQL query, but it isn't exactly working properly. I wrote  the following to fetch from my database where there is data that does not equal specified "ID Numbers"

```
SELECT * FROM `articles` 
WHERE `article_id` != 21 
 AND `article_id` != 81 
 AND `article_id` != 91 
 AND `article_content` LIKE '%$tag%' 
ORDER BY `article_id`
```

My query still fetches the same data sometimes though. Any thoughts on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Show some sample dataset

Answer (score 3):

Use `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `articles` 
WHERE `article_id` NOT IN (21,81,91)
  AND `article_content` LIKE '%$tag%' 
ORDER BY `article_id`
```

Comment: Would there be a syntax error if the data inside the NOT IN brackets was like (12,41,) with an additional comma at the end? And also, would there be a syntax error if that same bracket was empty like NOT IN () AND   ?

Comment: @Vimzy It would be as quick to try as to ask

Comment: @Vimzy: You will get an error. Something like [**this**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2ea52/10).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM `articles` 
WHERE `article_id` NOT IN (21,81,91,......)
AND `article_content` LIKE '%$tag%' 
ORDER BY `article_id`
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like :

```
SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `article_id` NOT IN (21, 81, 91) AND `article_content` LIKE
'%$tag%' ORDER BY `article_id`
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do something like this: *use `NOT IN`*

```
SELECT * FROM `articles` 
WHERE `article_id` NOT IN (21,81,91) -- add more ids in here
 AND `article_content` LIKE '%$tag%' 
ORDER BY `article_id`
```